# Passing parameters from different classes via this.props.navigation.getParam. (React Native))

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to pass data as parameter between 2 different classes(parent and child) which are located in 2 different js files. How would I be able to use

```js
()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('child', {
                name: 'muller',
                })
```

and obtain the values from in the child class via

```js
this.props.navigation.getParam('name')
```

When I tried this I'm always having cannot evaluate this.props.navigation in the childClass

**Below is the class that I've implemented the routestack**

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

/* ROUTING RULES */
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Parent: Parent,
      Child: Child,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Parent',
     }
    

   
  );
/* End */
  

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <RootStack />;
    }
  }
```

Comment: you're having trouble receiving the `props` you passed right? Can you provide your code in your `Child` so we can help correct your code for receiving the passed `props`

Answer (score 0):

You can access params by `this.props.navigation.state.params`.
In your case it will be `this.props.navigation.state.params.name`.

Also, if you you want to access `navigation` object in a component that is not declared in your `RootStack` then you should pass `navigation` object to that component as a prop. Alternatively you can use `withNavigation` provided by *react-navigation* like this -

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
   ... your component ...
}

export default withNavigaiton(YourComponent);
```

that way `YourComponent` will have access to `navigation` object and thus params.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Arpit, yep so I tried your solution (export child withNavigation) but it is still throwing "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.navigation')"

Comment: Can you console log `navigation` and see what you are receiving, also check `navigation.state.params` & Try accessing params like this `const params = this.props.navigation.state && this.props.navigation.state.params`  so that it works without crashing

Comment: Arpit, it is still throwing the same error. I've read the docs it is saying that withNavigation works only when you renders a component(it is on this compo that you can use withNavigation). But in my case I'm using this.props.navigation.navigate('child'... in order to access the compo. Any other suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Is there a way I could pass navigation via the rootStack?